# How many 6 digit numbers can you write?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

How many six-digit positive integers can you write, if each number must have strictly increasing digits from left to right

I thought it was 6! Butt hat is wrong.

How do you do these sort of problems using combinations he answer is:

$$\binom{9}{3}$$

How do they get that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

6! is all the way of ordering 6 distinct objects. It is not the correct answer for two reasons: one, which 6 objects are you considering? The digits 1 through 6? 3 through 9? Two, after specifying the objects, since you are considering all orderings (this is what ! does) you will get orderings which are not strictly increasing.

So how do they get $\binom{9}{3}$? Well first off notice since the problem specifies **strictly** increasing, no digits may repeat. Now we need to consider which 6 digits from 1 to 9 we will include in our number. $\binom{9}{6}$ represents all the ways  of selecting 6 distinct objects with no repeats from a pool of 9 distinct objects. Now we need to order them. But, given a set of distinct digits, theres only one way to arrange them in increasing order. Thus $1 * \binom{9}{6}$ is the total number of ways to select the type of number in question. Then note that $\binom{9}{6} = \binom{9}{3}$. This is because choosing 6 digits to include in your number is equivalent to choosing 3 digits to exclude. (in fact you could have started with $\binom{9}{3}$, but I think its more natural to consider which numbers are included first).

Comment: Doesn't that notation represent REPEAT ALLOWED? Ita a combination isn't it?

Comment: The distinction between combinations and permutations is that combinations count groups of objects without considering how they are ordered, not whether or not there are repeats. There are ways to count both combinations and permutations with or without repeats.

Comment: Then using combinations here will cause problem as for example 9 can be repeated?

Comment: No. $\binom{n}{m}$ means from a pool of $n$ objects select $m$ of them without repeating any and without considering the order they are selected.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to view this is to look at the increments from digit to digit.

The minimum initial digit is (presumably) $1$, and the maximum possible final digit is $9$, so there are $8$ increments. If the first digit is not $1$ or the last digit is not $9$, we can imagine that the relevant increments happen "outside" the number, before or after.

Each of the first five numbers definitely has an increment attached to it, so there are $3$ more increments to insert into the sequence, and $7$  places to put them, so we can play "stars & bars" and add them in ${7+3-1 \choose 3} = {9 \choose 3}$ ways.

Note that for non-strictly increasing digits (ie. never-decreasing digits), there are no  "attached" increments any more and there would be ${7+8-1 \choose 8} = {14 \choose 8}$ options.